# Microsoft Prism - multiple regions in a shell window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, prism

I am using Microsoft Prism to develop a WPF application. My WPF window has 2 regions. Here is XAML code describing my shell window:

```
<Window x:Class="Shell.ShellWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:cal="http://www.codeplex.com/prism"
        xmlns:commonConstants="clr-namespace:Common.Constants;assembly=Common"
        Height="479.851" Width="992.164">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Name ="Grid1" Grid.RowSpan="3" Margin="0,0,364,0">
            <ItemsControl cal:RegionManager.RegionName=
                  "{x:Static commonConstants:RegionNames.Region1}"/>
        </Grid>


        <Grid Name ="Grid2" Margin="662,0,0,0" Grid.RowSpan="3">
            <ItemsControl cal:RegionManager.RegionName=
                  "{x:Static commonConstants:RegionNames.Region2}"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

As you can see, each region is in a separate grid. Each region has its WPF user control associated with it. The first region has a button, and the second region has a textBox. I want to make it so that when the user presses button in the first region, some text (such as "Hello world") appears on the second region. I'm not sure if this is possible though, because I can't access directly from region1 a textBox in region2. If I had a function in user control of region2 that would set the text of textBox to what I want, how would I call that function if in region1 I don't have an instance of region2/view2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use EventAggregator in PRISM 4.0 for communicating between views. If you are using PRISM5.0 then use PubSubEvents
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/355473/Prism-EventAggregator-Sample